# class_copyPropertyList not working with RLMObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, property-list

I am trying to get the property list of an RLMObject programmatically like this:

```
MyRLMObject *myRLMObject = [[MyRLMObject alloc] init];
unsigned int count;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([myRLMObject class], &count);
```

but it returns null.

This works well with normal classes derived from NSObject.

I put a breakpoint and found that myRLMObject is actually structured as

```
  (RLMStandalone_MyRLMObject *) 0x12c5c9cf0
    MyRLMObject
      RLMObject
      _strName = (NSString *) nil
      _strId = (NSString *) nil
```

("strName" and "strId" are the properties I defined and want to get from the list.)

With a normal class derived from NSObject, I got this

```
  (MyNSObject *) 0x12c5cab40
    NSObject
    _strName = (NSString *) nil
    _strId = (NSString *) nil
```

I think the reason should be that Realm added a "RLMStandalone_MyRLMObject" outside the class structure and caused class_copyPropertyList fail to work.

Is there any workaround for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? `class_copyPropertyList` only retrieves the properties declared in that specific class, not any superclasses. If you'd like to know all declared properties you can walk the inheritance hierarchy. If for some reason you just want to know which properties Realm is managing, you can use `-[RLMObject objectSchema]` to retrieve that information without restoring to the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: I think https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4949 might help you if you are still looking for retrieving runtime properties of RLMObject.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is because `RLMObject` have dynamic properties, that means they will be created and added to each object on the runtime, and you can't know when it will happen.